# Load Qtablewidget with a list

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a list like below

```
[('John', datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 5, 0, 54), datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 26, 22, 51, 36)),
('Rex', datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 26, 22, 51, 36), datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 15, 10, 22, 48)),
('Watson', datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 15, 10, 22, 48), datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 8, 13, 33, 36)), 
('Manila', datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 8, 13, 33, 36), datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 29, 6, 18)), 
('Pete', datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 29, 6, 18), datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 6, 18, 50, 24)), 
('Mathew', datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 6, 18, 50, 24), datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 31, 3, 14, 24))]
```

I have created a UI like below 
[Qtablewidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtxzH.png)

How can i add the Name in `Name` column, First date in `From` column and second date in `To` column. i tried `setitem` on push button click but it did not work

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    import datetime
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 311, 301))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 430, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "From"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "To"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onload)
    def onload(self):
        for i in mainlist:
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i[1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can i make this work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it's like working with 2D array

- get number of rows and colums of your data:

  ```
  numcols = len(data[0])   # ( to get number of columns, count number of values in first row( first row is data[0]))

  numrows = len(data)   # (to get number of rows, count number of values(which are arrays) in data(2D array))
  ```
- Set dimensions of QTableWidget:

  ```
  self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(numcols)

  self.tableWidget.setRowCount(numrows)
  ```
- Use basic nasted for loop to pass over your data(2D array):
  in every step, set value from your data (2D array) into the same position in QTableWidget:

  ```
  self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, QTableWidgetItem((data[row][column])))
  ```

  where:

  - row, column = indexes in QTableWidget
  - QTableWidgetItem((data[row][column])) = value which you will set in QTableWidget

**note:** QTableWidgetItem(const QString &text)

The QTableWidgetItem class provides an item for use with the QTableWidget class

**note:** you cant pass datetime into QTableWidgetItem , because of that you need to check if value you are trying to set into QTableWidget is datetime, if it is, you need to convert datetime to string:

```
if isinstance(data[row][column], datetime.datetime):

     ...data[row][column].strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Full code:

```
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem
    from datetime import datetime
    import datetime

    data = [('John', datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 5, 0, 54), datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 26, 22, 51, 36)),
    ('Rex', datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 26, 22, 51, 36), datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 15, 10, 22, 48)),
    ('Watson', datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 15, 10, 22, 48), datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 8, 13, 33, 36)),
    ('Manila', datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 8, 13, 33, 36), datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 29, 6, 18)),
    ('Pete', datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 29, 6, 18), datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 6, 18, 50, 24)),
    ('Mathew', datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 6, 18, 50, 24), datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 31, 3, 14, 24))]

    numrows = len(data)  # 6 rows in your example
    numcols = len(data[0])  # 3 columns in your example

    # Set colums and rows in QTableWidget
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(numcols)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(numrows)

    # Loops to add values into QTableWidget
    for row in range(numrows):
        for column in range(numcols):
            # Check if value datatime, if True convert to string 
            if isinstance(data[row][column], datetime.datetime):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, QTableWidgetItem((data[row][column].strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))))
            else:
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, QTableWidgetItem((data[row][column])))
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks,this works, although i could understand the code, would you mind adding some bit of explanation..Thanks

Comment: I just edited my post with some more explanations, I hope so it will help :)