# PyQt5 how do I load data to tablewidget from a arraylist

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm new to python and PyQt so be patient with me.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get the data to load into the tablewidget.
The data is stored in a arraylist that is made from the dog class in the Dog.py file.

Is there a better/easier way to make/load data into the tablewidget when using arraylist and classes?

This is the error I get when i try to run the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/unseensnick/VS Code Projects/python projects/java assignments in python/DogRegistry/Main.py", line 39, in <module>
    main = DogRegistry()
  File "/home/unseensnick/VS Code Projects/python projects/java assignments in python/DogRegistry/Main.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loadData()
  File "/home/unseensnick/VS Code Projects/python projects/java assignments in python/DogRegistry/Main.py", line 30, in loadData
    self.dogTable.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(dog["name"]))
TypeError: 'Dog' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is my current code:

Main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from Dog import Dog

class DogRegistry(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DogRegistry, self).__init__()
        loadUi("DogRegistry.ui", self)
        self.dogTable.setColumnWidth(0,165)
        self.dogTable.setColumnWidth(1,165)
        self.dogTable.setColumnWidth(2,90)
        self.dogTable.setColumnWidth(3,90)
        self.dogTable.setColumnWidth(4,90)
        self.loadData()
        
    def loadData(self):
        dogs = []
        dogs.append( Dog("Luna","Eurasier", 3, 22))
        #dogs.append( Dog("Sky","Tax", 3, 3))
        #dogs.append( Dog("Skye","Dachshund", 4, 5))
        #dogs.append( Dog("Bella","Dachs", 2, 3))
        
        row = 0
        self.dogTable.setRowCount(len(dogs))
        for dog in dogs:
            self.dogTable.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(dog["name"]))
            self.dogTable.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(dog["breed"]))
            self.dogTable.setItem(row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(dog["age"])))
            self.dogTable.setItem(row, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(dog["weight"])))
            self.dogTable.setItem(row, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(dog["tailLength"])))
            row = row + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = DogRegistry()
    widget = QStackedWidget()
    widget.addWidget(main)
    widget.setFixedHeight(900)
    widget.setFixedWidth(1200)    
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Dog.py

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, breed, age, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.breed = breed
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.tailLength = self.getTailLength()
            
    def getTailLength(self):
        if(self.breed.lower() == "tax" or self.breed.lower() == "dachs" or self.breed.lower() == "dachshund"):
            return 3.7
        else:
            return (self.age * self.weight) / 10.0
        
    def getName(self):
        return self.name
    
    def setName(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def getBreed(self):
        return self.breed
    
    def setBreed(self, breed):
        self.breed = breed
        
    def getAge(self):
        return self.age
    
    def setAge(self, age):
        self.age = age
        
    def getWeight(self):
        return self.weight
    
    def setName(self, weight):
        self.weight = weight
```

GUI.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>mainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="mainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1200</width>
    <height>900</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>1200</width>
    <height>900</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>1200</width>
    <height>900</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="mainWidget" native="true">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1200</width>
     <height>900</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QWidget#mainWidget{
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(31, 64, 55, 255), stop:1 rgba(153, 242, 200, 255));
}
QWidget#mainWidgetLeft{
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
QWidget#mainWidgetRight{
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}</string>
   </property>
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <property name="spacing">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <item>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="mainWidgetLeft" native="true">
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>500</width>
        <height>900</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true"/>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
       <property name="spacing">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="leftMargin">
        <number>60</number>
       </property>
       <property name="topMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="rightMargin">
        <number>60</number>
       </property>
       <property name="bottomMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <item>
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeType">
          <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>160</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="id">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>340</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>11</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>ID:</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="idInput">
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>16777215</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>12</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="readOnly">
          <bool>true</bool>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="name">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>340</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>11</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Name:</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="nameInput">
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>16777215</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>12</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="breed">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>340</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>11</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Breed:</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="breedInput">
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>16777215</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>12</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="age">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>340</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>11</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Age:</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="ageInput">
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>16777215</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>12</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="weigth">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>340</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>11</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Weight:</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="weightInput">
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>16777215</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>12</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
         <property name="spacing">
          <number>60</number>
         </property>
         <property name="leftMargin">
          <number>100</number>
         </property>
         <property name="topMargin">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
         <property name="rightMargin">
          <number>100</number>
         </property>
         <property name="bottomMargin">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="submitBtn">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>0</width>
             <height>35</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>12</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Submit</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="editBtn">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>0</width>
             <height>35</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>12</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Edit</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item>
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeType">
          <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>240</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="mainWidgetRight" native="true">
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>700</width>
        <height>900</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true"/>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
       <property name="spacing">
        <number>40</number>
       </property>
       <property name="leftMargin">
        <number>10</number>
       </property>
       <property name="topMargin">
        <number>100</number>
       </property>
       <property name="rightMargin">
        <number>60</number>
       </property>
       <property name="bottomMargin">
        <number>60</number>
       </property>
       <item>
        <widget class="QTableWidget" name="dogTable">
         <column>
          <property name="text">
           <string>Name</string>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <pointsize>12</pointsize>
           </font>
          </property>
         </column>
         <column>
          <property name="text">
           <string>Breed</string>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <pointsize>12</pointsize>
           </font>
          </property>
         </column>
         <column>
          <property name="text">
           <string>Age</string>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <pointsize>12</pointsize>
           </font>
          </property>
         </column>
         <column>
          <property name="text">
           <string>Weight</string>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <pointsize>12</pointsize>
           </font>
          </property>
         </column>
         <column>
          <property name="text">
           <string>Tail-length</string>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <pointsize>12</pointsize>
           </font>
          </property>
         </column>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_5">
         <property name="spacing">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="leftMargin">
          <number>240</number>
         </property>
         <property name="rightMargin">
          <number>240</number>
         </property>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="removeBtn">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>0</width>
             <height>35</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>12</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Remove</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: A similar discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54691624/load-qtablewidget-with-a-list A simple for in loop would suffice

Comment: @Snickers Why are you using e.g. `dog["name"]` rather than `dog.name` or `dog.getName()`?

Comment: @Snickers Please don't put the answer in the question, use the *answer* field for that. Also, python is not javascript, you cannot access attributes using the `object["attribute"]` syntax, that only works for dictionaries or objects that provide the `__getitem__` interface and accept strings.

Comment: @musicamante sorry didn't know that since it was my first post

Comment: @Snickers Don't worry, no problem. Please take your time to carefully follow the [tour], read [ask], [answer] and review the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648). Remember that this is not a forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @ekhumoro's comment I got it to work.

here is the code:

Main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from Dog import Dog

class DogRegistry(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DogRegistry, self).__init__()
        loadUi("DogRegistry.ui", self)
        self.dogTable.setColumnWidth(0,165)
        self.dogTable.setColumnWidth(1,165)
        self.dogTable.setColumnWidth(2,90)
        self.dogTable.setColumnWidth(3,90)
        self.dogTable.setColumnWidth(4,90)
        self.loadData()
        
    def loadData(self):
        dogs = []
        dogs.append( Dog("Luna","Eurasier", 3, 22))
        #dogs.append( Dog("Sky","Tax", 3, 3))
        #dogs.append( Dog("Skye","Dachshund", 4, 5))
        #dogs.append( Dog("Bella","Dachs", 2, 3))
        
        row = 0
        self.dogTable.setRowCount(len(dogs))
        for dog in dogs:
            self.dogTable.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(dog.getName()))
            self.dogTable.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(dog.getBreed()))
            self.dogTable.setItem(row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(dog.getAge())))
            self.dogTable.setItem(row, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(dog.getWeight())))
            self.dogTable.setItem(row, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(dog.getTailLength())))
            row = row + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = DogRegistry()
    widget = QStackedWidget()
    widget.addWidget(main)
    widget.setFixedHeight(900)
    widget.setFixedWidth(1200)    
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```